# How to change class name and data in element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change class name and data in element using javascript ?

Now i can change class name from `class="xxx"` to `class="yyy"` it's ok.

But i want to change

```
<img src="http://iconshow.me/media/images/Mixed/Free-Flat-UI-Icons/png/128/heart-24-128.png"/>
```

to

```
<img src="http://image.ohozaa.com/i/c70/cLBh71.png"/>
```

this my demo

http://jsfiddle.net/dFp6f/8/

this is javascript code

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    $("#demo").addClass("yyy").removeClass("xxx");
}
</script>
```

How to do ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/af2uq3oz/ Use `.prop()` to change src property of img

Comment: @robert ioersed  check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr` method to changing image src:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#demo").addClass("yyy").removeClass("xxx");
    $("img").attr("src", "http://image.ohozaa.com/i/c70/cLBh71.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
     $("#demo").addClass("yyy").removeClass("xxx");
     $("#demo img").attr("src","http://image.ohozaa.com/i/c70/cLBh71.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check updated code here on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/dFp6f/9/)   update in function

```
function myFunction() {
   $("#demo").addClass("yyy").removeClass("xxx");
   $("#demo img").attr('src','http://image.ohozaa.com/i/c70/cLBh71.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this..

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#demo").addClass("yyy").removeClass("xxx").find('img').prop('src', 'http://image.ohozaa.com/i/c70/cLBh71.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```js
var src = "http://image.ohozaa.com/i/c70/cLBh71.png";

$('img').attr('src', function(){
    return src;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://iconshow.me/media/images/Mixed/Free-Flat-UI-Icons/png/128/heart-24-128.png"/>
```